# How can I divide with multiple decimals

Tags: solidity

I am running into some issues trying to convert this equation into solidity friendly code

`x * (0.933333 + y/z/3.75)`

I've tried converting values in the following way, but end up w/ incorrect results. Any ideas?

```
uint y = 2294;
uint z = 1293;
uint a = 0.93333 * 10 ** 18;
uint b = y / z * 10 ** 18;
uint c = 3.75 * 10 ** 18;
```

Comment: You might want to use a fixed-point math library. Check out [PRBMath](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-math).

Answer (score 0):

Solidity's support for decimal numbers is basically non-existing. Therefore you can't use decimal numbers in Solidity.

What you need to do is first convert it the number to an integer, for example `uint a = 93333 * 10 ** 13`. Do the same for all your decimal numbers.

Assuming you need the real result in the end (or, more like it, a rounded integer version of it), you can just divide by *10**18*.

Comment: That's what I am doing

Comment: No, you are using explicit decimal places in your numbers

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm showing how I convert the decimals at the bottom of my question. The issue was dividing by 3.75 - even if I converted via 10 ** 18 it would be incorrect because y and z divide first and had already been converted. So I did `uint b = y * 10 ** 18/z; uint c = (b / 375) * 100;`